# Pagination of abstract type while inserting data

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am writing an application that parses data and inserts it to Elastic Search. The insertion process is time consuming and I'm required to allow my users to view the inserted data while insertion still continues. All my db elements implement a basic interface called `IExtractionObject`. I tried the following code:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IExtractionObject> GetItems(IEnumerable<Type> types, long objectCategory, int size = 50)
        {
            var from = 0;
            var result = Search(types, objectCategory, from, size);
            while(result.Documents.Any())
            {
                foreach (var extractionObject in result.Documents)
                {
                    yield return extractionObject;
                }
                from += size + 1;
                result = Search(types, objectCategory, from, size);
            }
        }

        private IQueryResponse<IExtractionObject> Search(IEnumerable<Type> types, long objectCategory, int from, int size)
        {
            return ElasticClient.Search<IExtractionObject>(srch => srch
                .Types(types.Distinct())
                .Query(q => q.Term(i => i.ObjectCategory, objectCategory))
                .From(from)
                .Size(size));
        }
```

My problem is that when I have an ammount of over 500 elements, I almost always extract the same element twice. I read that I should use the `Scroll` method, but I see it requires a concrete type. Is there another way to handle this, or is there a way to load abstract data via `Scroll`.

Please help,

Izhar

Comment: Scrolling doesn't require a concrete `_type`.  A scroll is just like a cursor on an existing search.  You just keep pulling more results from the original search.

Comment: I've seen the object come out in a json format. How do I deserialize them to .Net objects?

Comment: No idea :) How do you deserialize any of the JSON responses from Elasticsearch into .Net objects?  I'm guessing that that is something your application will need to implement.

Comment: Nest does that for me. I guess I'd look at the code to realize how this is done